# Optimizing C# loop comparison of two very large lists

Tags: c#, list, loops, optimization, .net-core

Before you read my explanation I want to tell you that I need to optimize processing time for comparing two huge c# lists, index by index in a nested loop.

Its a .Net Core App which I am creating with C# of course.

In my algorithm I have to create a very long list with some ranges of integers, like this.

```
internal class Global
{
    public string ChromosomeName { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int end { get; set; }
    public string Cluster { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
} 
var globals = new List<Global>();// somewhere in my method.
```

now this list will be very huge for example it will have values stored like this. This is my main list so its named 'globals'

```
index 0 = start=1, end=400 ....
index 1 = start=401, end=800....
index (last) = start= 45090000 , end= 45090400 ...
```

These are just rough estimate values so that you understand that it's going to be a huge list.

Now in my algorithm what I actually have to do is

- So I take one text file, read that file and store its data in another list exactly with the same properties as shown above in the code.
- Now I have 2 lists, globals list and other list which i read from the file.
- Both of them are very huge lists
- Now I have to compare both of them index by index in a nested loop.
- Outer loop will be iterating my globals list and inner loop will be iterating my other list ( which i read from the file).
- After I finish the nested loops one time, I read another file and created another list and then compare that list with globals list in same manner..
- So there will be one global list which will be compared index by index in a nested loop with around 10 more lists and all of them being nearly as huge as global list itself.

**Below is pseudocode shown for the nested foreach loops.**

```
foreach(var item in globals)
{
    var value=0;
    foreach(var item2 in otherHugeList)
    {
        compareMethod(item,item2);
        //below is the actual code of wht kind of comparison I am doing,     just if i guyx want to know, I am actually finding the overlap between two ranges.
       //value += Math.Max(0, Math.Min(range1.end, EndList[i]) -  Math.Max(range1.start, StartList[i]) + 1);
    }
}
```

What is the fastest way I can do this, because right now it takes more than hours and I get frustrated and I cancel the process because I don't know how long its going to take. So I am not even able to get my results on smaller files.

I need to know the fastest possible way to do this, should I use any library compatible with .Net core? or multithreading somehow? I am not that good with threading concepts though.

P.S: I have used Parallel.ForEach and its difference on performance is negligible.

Comment: This looks/sounds like the perfect job for TPL Dataflow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You've said what you're doing but not why you're doing it. What's the point of comparing the two lists?  If the question is "are these lists different?" then that is much faster to answer than "what are all the differences?"

Comment: I did not understand a single word from those steps you said... what are you trying to do? it seems like XY problem.

Comment: If your conclusion "I have to compare both of them index by index" is correct then you can only improve speed by improving the code that compares the items. You mention ranges, could you perhaps split the erh "main list" in multiple smaller lists that each cover a smaller range? And if the lists are ordered by range as in the example, you could "guesstimate" the index to start finding matches at.

Comment: I will update my question and explain the steps properly @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: I have updated the steps @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: Do you have self-overlaps between `start..end` intervals on the *same* list? In other words, could your global list have `start=100, end=200` and then `start=180, end=400`?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll can you please tell me how can I use TPL dataflow in my code and in my algo ? because as I told u my multithreading concepts arent tht good, I would really appreciate if u could give me an example code. Thankyou

Comment: Side-note: why don't you use a database instead of large files?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight
very thoughtful question u asked, and the answer is NO, my global list will not self overlap, it will always be like this, 1-400, 401-800 and so on, and all the other lists which I will read from the file will have different kind of index ranges, but they will not self overlap as well, so in short : "None of my lists will have self overlapping values". Thanks in advance if u have a brilliant solution to my problem :)

Comment: For fastest comparison I think I would use a database.  I would first insert first file into a new datatable.  Then add new column to datatable for each additional file.  Then after all data is loaded you can compare each property across all the columns.  The database is optimized better for reading large files than the I/O methods inside of c#.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis thankyou I tried guesing the start and end index and it has improved my speed a little bit bcz now it iterates relatively less times. but I still need to improve it a lot morem because its still not good enough for my huge data.

Comment: @jdweng can you please post an answer with a short example? so i CAN understand a bit better? , are you talking about a proper sql database or just a datatable object? please show some code example. Thankyou

Comment: I was talking about a table in the database.  Yes you can use SQL Server.  The I/O methods are real efficient.  You can use SQLCMD.exe which is a command line interface to the SQL Server that comes with SQL Server.  It is excellent in reading very large files.

Comment: actually i tried sql server, but the problem is this app is .netcore app and will be running on linux as well, and even with ,netcore linux doesnt have support of sql server, I tried sqlite with,netcore but its I/O methods for bulk data is too slow, there are some libraries to make it fast but they also dont work with.netcore they work with normal .net only . sadly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to make element-by-element comparisons of two lists with 10<sup>6</sup> items each, there's 10<sup>12</sup> comparisons that you need to make. It leaves you no hope to finish in a sane amount of time, so the key to solving this problem is to drastically reduce the number of comparisons.

The exact approach to making the reduction depends on the kind of comparison that you are running, so let's use overlap computation from your post as an example.

You know that there is no overlap between ranges R and Q when one of the statements below is true:

- Upper bound of R is below the lower bound of Q, or
- Lower bound of R is above the upper bound of Q.

This wouldn't help if your ranges appear on the list in random order. However, if you sort your ranges on the lower bound, and resolve ties by the upper bound, you will be able to use binary search to find the relevant portion of the list for each range you compare, i.e. the elements for which the overlap is possible.

Assuming that there is little overlap among ranges on the same list, this will reduce the number of comparisons from roughly a million per element to well under a hundred per element, resulting in 1000-fold increase in performance.

> None of my lists will have self-overlapping ranges *(comment)*

Then you can use a variation of the [*merge algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) by sorting both range lists, and then iterating them in a single loop. Set indexes into two arrays to zero, then walk both lists one step at a time. If the current range on the global list is below the `start` level of the current range on the comparison list, move on to the next element of the global list; otherwise, move on to the next element of the comparison list. The two indexes will "chase" each other until you reach the end of both lists after 2M increments.

Comment: ur answer makes sense, and also all my ranges are sorted, can you please show me a code example of binary searched, i do have sorted ranges, but I didnt clearly understand how will I use binary search to find relevent portions of the list as u mentioned above.

Comment: I am understanding your merge algorithm logic and I got it, I only have one question, both lists will have different number of elements in them, and it may give index out of bound error when one of them is finished, how do I manage this situation ?

Comment: @touseef When one of the lists runs out of elements, you are done, because an overlap is no longer possible. Note that your algorithm will be a little trickier than a plain merge, because when you see an overlap you would need to explore both lists to see when the overlap ends. Essentially, it's a many-to-many matching, for example `10-20,21-30,31-40` and `15-35,36-45` produce four overlaps, with elements on both sides matching to more than one element on the opposite side.